# in which table tax for order is stored in database?

Tags: php, woocommerce, woothemes

I am developing the phonegap app for woocommerce store, Now I am stuck. I need to create order manually. For that reason, I want to know where is the taxes for particular order is stored? Also where is the shipping method for particular order in database stored?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Both the taxes & shipping detail for a particular order is stored in table: [`woocommerce_order_itemmeta`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description#table-woocommerce_order_itemmeta).

You can identify taxes & shipping calculated on a particular order by checking the `order_item_id` column of any entry.

Make sure you have enabled Shipping/Taxes modules under the WooCommerce settings properly.

Also, you can check what type of info other tables store [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description).